# How to put icons in disorder position in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Just start  learning Android programming, I want to draw some rectangles or put some icons in disorder positions.
something like this [image]

When clicking the rectangle a new window pops out. but I'm not sure which layouts should I use, I tried grid view, dragged 6 grids into the screen, and then I don't know what to do next... I'm reading this article:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html, but it seems can't solve my problem, hope you guys can give me some hints. Thanks

Update:
from official tutorial, there is only one id in main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:id="@+id/**gridview**"
  ....
/>
```

then in onCreate method, the GridView is captured from the layout with `findViewById(int)`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.**gridview**);
```

My problem is that I have 6 ids in `main.xml`, which are gridlayout1 gridlayout2.....gridlayout6.
something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="**@+id/gridLayout1"** 
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gridLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp" >
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

How can I call these ids in one `onCreate` method? or I was doing it totally wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide your full code?

Comment: @L.Butz I haven't start coding yet.. but I will update my question and make it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you wanna use a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) or a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and place Buttons with a custom background on fix positions on it. You will get problems with different screen sizes though.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look very "Androidy" what you're trying to do. If I really wanted a chaotic layout like this I think I would just draw to a Canvas.